# css get value from html

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net

```
.font-title
{
  color: " + Label1.Text + ";
}

<asp:Label Text="Red" runat="server" ID="Label1" />
```

I was wondering, is there any possible approach to the above solution? javascript is allowed.

i've been google for week and can't seems to get any idea.

----------EDITED-----------------

```
var color = document.getElementById('Label1').innerHTML;

var fontTitle = document.getElementsByClassName('font-title')[0];
fontTitle.getElementsByClassName('main-title');

for (var i = 0; i < fontTitle.length; i++) {
         fontTitle[i].style.color = color;
}

 <asp:Label Text="Red" runat="server" ID="Label1" />
       <div class="font-title">            
          <div class="main-title">
             Main Title
          </div>
          <div class="sub-title">
             This is sub title
         </div>
       </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible with pure css.

However, using javascript

```
var color = document.getElementById('Label1').textContent;
var fontTitles = document.getElementByClassName('font-title');
for(var i = 0; i < fontTitles.length; i++){
    fontTitles[i].style.color = color;
}
```

```js
var color = document.getElementById('Label1').textContent;

var fontTitles = document.getElementsByClassName('font-title');

for (var i = 0; i < fontTitles.length; i++) {
  var mainTitles = document.getElementsByClassName('main-title');
  for (var j = 0; j < fontTitles.length; j++) {
    mainTitles[j].style.color = color;
  }
}
```

```html
<label id="Label1">red
</label>
<div class="font-title">
  <div class="main-title">
    Main Title
  </div>
  <div class="sub-title">
    This is sub title
  </div>
</div>

<div class="font-title">
  <div class="main-title">
    Main Title
  </div>
  <div class="sub-title">
    This is sub title
  </div>
</div>

<div class="font-title">
  <div class="main-title">
    Main Title
  </div>
  <div class="sub-title">
    This is sub title
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: im not understand the usage of the for loop

Comment: @user3431239, because you may have multiple elements with class `font-title`

Comment: how about if there is a subclass, eg. `.font-title .main-title` and `.font-title .sub-title`. `getElementsByClassName('font-title main-title')` is not working

Comment: @user3431239, right. You need to store the parent in a variable, then do it like `var fontTitle = document.getElementsByClassName('font-title')[0];fontTitle.getElementsByClassName('sub-title');`